# Why does Hardhat's just deployed contract.address differ from the real one?

Tags: solidity, addresses, hardhat-deploy

I am deploying a contract on the testnet with hardhat, but the address returned is not the real address the contract is at in the blockchain.

I am following [hardhat's guide](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/deploying-to-a-live-network.html).

Code:

```
async function main() {
  const TokenContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token");
  const token = await TokenContract.deploy();
  await token.deployed();

  console.log("Token deployed to:", token.address);
}
```

`Token deployed to: 0x684c903c66D69777377f0945052160C9f778d689`

At that address, though, I see a contract that is not mine! If I look into my wallet's transaction in the explorer I can find the contract creation transaction and the real contract, here::
[image: real address]

How come?

Comment: Why do you think your deployed contract is the address you are showing on the screenshot? can you give more detail?

Comment: @JulissaDC I just checked the transactions of my address and saw that there was one about a contract generation. I followed it and I saw that that one was the generated contract. It corresponds with what I deployed.